# Error al insertar datos de un api a SQLite con Kotlin

Tags: api, kotlin, sqlite

al momento de querer ingresar los datos de una api a SQLite con Kotlin - Volley, me sale el siguiente mensaje:

I/Choreographer: Skipped 299 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Me he informado un poco sobre el tema, pero no tengo clara la manera de solucionarlo, el código con el cual realizo el registro es el siguiente:

```
fun callNetworkConnection() {
    val btnUpd = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnUpd)
    network = Network(application)
    network.observe(this, { isConnected ->
        if (isConnected) {


            btnUpd.setOnClickListener {
                solicitudHTTP("http://199.241.218.53:60000/VLVTI/Vistas/rrhh/action/activity_to_costCenter.php")
            }

            //https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=3530597&appid=79dc5b927ee95b81ad03f7213c49b87b
        }else{
            btnUpd.isEnabled = false
            }
        })
    }
```

Y en la función solicitudHTTP() esta el siguiente código:

```
    private fun solicitudHTTP(url: String){
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    val stringRequest = StringRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, url, Response.Listener<String>
        { response ->
            try {
                val jsonArray = JSONArray(response)
                for(i in 0 until jsonArray.length()){
                    val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                    var idconsumidor = jsonObject.getString("IDCONSUMIDOR")
                    var descripcion = jsonObject.getString("DESCRIPCION")

                    crud?.insertActivity(activityModel( idconsumidor, descripcion))
                    
                }

            }catch (e:Exception){

            }
        },

        Response.ErrorListener { error ->

            error.message?.let { Log.d("HTTP_REQUEST", it) }

        })
    queue.add(stringRequest)
}
```

El mensaje me aparece cada que presiono el botón que ejecuta la función, alguien sabe como solucionarlo y que me pueda insertar los datos de manera correcta.

Answer (score 0):

acabo de solucionar mi problema, leyendo llegué a conoces sobre las Corrutinas de Kotlin, y es lo que usé para solucionar mi problema, adjunto el código con la solución:

```
fun callNetworkConnection() {
    val btnUpd = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnUpd)
    network = Network(application)
    network.observe(this, { isConnected ->
        if (isConnected) {

            btnUpd.setOnClickListener {
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch { <-- Uso de la corrutina.

                    solicitudHTTP("http://199.241.218.53:60000/VLVTI/Vistas/rrhh/action/activity_to_costCenter.php")

                }

            }

            //https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=3530597&appid=79dc5b927ee95b81ad03f7213c49b87b
        }else{
            btnUpd.isEnabled = false
            }
        })
    }
```